# how to handle PageRequestManagerTimeoutException in ASP.net Web Application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a ASP.NET web application that tryies to download some files from a remote server by login the server. While I try to download a file it works fine with small files but a It shows following exception while downloading a file of 750 KB.

[image]

I m defining the `HTTPRequest Timout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;`

I m reading the files from server using this code

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            using (Stream input = getResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (FileStream output = new FileStream(saveTo1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
```

What could possible be creating this problem?

> Also When I click on `Ignore` or `Continue` It continues the download
>   smoothly further. How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to handle the timeout exception, you can handle it with javascript. Add this to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(requestEndHandler );

// This function will handle the end request event
function requestEndHandler(sender, args) {
   if( args.get_error() ){
      document.getElementById("errorMessageLabel").innerText = 
         args.get_error().description;
       args.set_errorHandled(true);
   }
}

</script>
...

<span id="errorMessageLabel"></span>
```

Also if you want, you can increase AsyncPostBackTimeOut by sdding `AsyncPostBackTimeOut="600"//Time` to your script manager.:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"

AsyncPostBackTimeOut="600" >

</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: The way i handled time out is setting its value to -1 that is unlimited.

Comment: Do not use unlimited value if not critically important. Having a limited value is a safe bet.

Comment: This time value is in miliseconds

Comment: No seconds, did the function help?

Comment: Wow that worked. Not the function but jus setting the `AsyncPostBackTimeOut="60"`. Thanks :)